# is there a way to intercept the begin and end Conversation in CDI?

Tags: java, cdi, weld, jboss-weld

I would like to intercept calls to methods `conversation.begin()` and `conversation.end()`.

To do this, I have developed an interceptor binding that I aim to dynamically assign to the `Conversation` class through a CDI portable extension.

However, I can not find how to access to the `Conversation` class since it is not observed in the `ProcessAnnotatedType` event where usually i do this process to my defined beans.

See the code as an example:

```
public class MethodCallsInterceptorExt implements Extension {
        
    void processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?> event) {  
        if (isConvesationBean(event)) { // This condition is never true
            event.configureAnnotatedType().add(new MyInterceptorBinding());
        }
    }
}
```

Is this solution at least partially correct?
Is there any viable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```java
public class ConversationObserver {

    public void onStart(@Observes @Initialized(ConversationScoped.class) ServletRequest request) {}

    public void onEnd(@Observes @Destroyed(ConversationScoped.class) ServletRequest request) {}
}
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html